# AndroidStudio - Using ListView.addFooterView

Tags: android, listview

I want to use this method to create a "ADD String" button to my List which runs through a String Array.

It's just a practice exercise and I can't seem to do this.

My objective is to add a Item to the list, that when clicked. Will prompt the user to add another String to the list, however I can't seem to add the footer. Anything I can use?

onCreate() method in the MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Show array
    String favTVShows[] = {"Naruto", "One Piece", "Kuroko no Basket", "Tokyo Ghoul", "Parasyte - the maxim -", "Nanatsu no Taizai"};

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, favTVShows);

    //Add xml a ListView e set o MyAdapter.class
    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.extras, null);
    theListView.addFooterView(v);
    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);


    //Quando CLICK num item da toast.
    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            String tvShowPicked = "You selected " + String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvShowPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });



}
```

**EDIT**:Can't post images, but here's how it's showing right now.
  http://puu.sh/g42zV/5e451eeeae.jpg

Comment: Please show what you think is the best code that you've tried so far

Comment: Yup, show some code so we can help you build on it.

Comment: I've edited to include code, and a little printscrn on how it looks.